# Call to undefined function _()

Tags: laravel

I am having trouble with this error,

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined function _() (View: C:\Codes\web-is\resources\views\layouts\client.blade.php)
```

and it is pointing in this code

```
<title><?php echo e(_('This is title')); ?></title>
```

I think it is in the `_()` of Laravel helper, but it should be working right.

I really do not know what is going on, there is a live server that working fine with the code. I just tried to clone the repo to my laptop and install necessary requirements such as `PHP`, `IIS` is my web server. I also sure that PHP extensions are installed, I can see it in `phpinfo()`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Laravel helper function to get translation string is `__()`, not `_()`. Note the two, double underscores **__**.

See this link; https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L820

Comment: I am not sure what happens, I don't remember any that I have edited this code or somewhat. Anyway, appreciate it.